# GraphQL subscription to internal service through public gateway service

Tags: apollo, nestjs, graphql-subscriptions

I have an "internal" service and a public facing API gateway service.  I want to implement a graphql subscription so that clients can receive asynchronous real time updates from the internal service, but only the public service is exposed.  I have the subscription on the internal service working if I interact with it directly.  However, I don't know how to subscribe to the internal service through the public facing API gateway service.

Is what I am trying to do possible and is it even the correct approach?  I am new to graphql and I can't seem to find any "advanced" examples showing people doing this.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The graphql subscription must be implemented in the public facing service.  Then you can choose from a variety of methods to facilitate the communication from the internal service to the public service (redis pubSub, rabbitmq, etc) which would then trigger the subscription publishing.

I hope this helps someone.